# Subtle difference in XMLSerializer in Firefox vs Chrome?

Tags: xml, json, google-chrome, firefox, xmlserializer

The following snippet of code converts a Javascript object into an XML string using the createDocument and XMLSerializer APIs. The problem is that it generates different outputs on Chrome (23.0.1271.101) and Firefox (14.0.1) browsers.

```
var item = { _dto: {...} }; // the 'model' object
var xmlDto = $('<Column />'); // this is eventually serialized and sent to the server
var optionalTags = ['Abstract', 'Note', 'Size', 'Digits', 'Nullable', 'AutoUpdate', 'DataType'];

// convert badgerfish JSON back to XML.
// use XML because it is not possible serialize JSON and preserve key order.
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("http://example.org/v1", "Column", null);
var root = xmlDoc.childNodes[0];
var nameTag = xmlDoc.createElement("Name");
nameTag.setAttribute('uuid', item._dto['Name']['@uuid']);
nameTag.textContent=item._dto['Name']['$'];
root.appendChild(nameTag);
optionalTags.map(function (tagName) {
    var tag = xmlDoc.createElement(tagName);
    tag.textContent=item._dto[tagName];
    if (item._dto.hasOwnProperty(tagName)) {
        tag.textContent=item._dto[tagName];
        root.appendChild(tag);
    }
});

var xmlStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc);
xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+xmlStr;
```

On Chrome, the following desired/expected output is generated:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Column xmlns="http://example.org/v1">
          <Name uuid="001b5cbe-bab7-4880-90b6-9e8f47f6e4af">FAILED_ID</Name>
          <Size>38</Size>
          <Digits>0</Digits>
          <Nullable>true</Nullable>
          <AutoUpdate>false</AutoUpdate>
          <DataType>NUMERIC</DataType>
    </Column>
```

But in Firefox, the generated output has the `xmlns` attribute inserted in every tag with an empty value:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
     <Column xmlns="http://example.org/v1">
          <Name xmlns="" uuid="001b5cbe-bab7-4880-90b6-9e8f47f6e4af">FAILED_ID</Name>
          <Size xmlns="">38</Size>
          <Digits xmlns="">0</Digits>
          <Nullable xmlns="">true</Nullable>
          <AutoUpdate xmlns="">false</AutoUpdate>
          <DataType xmlns="">NUMERIC</DataType>
     </Column>
```

It looks like the XMLSerializer in Firefox and Chrome have subtle differences but I need to verify this. In any case, the Firefox output is invalid XML. Can somebody shed some light on this?

Is there a better way to generate an XML document in the browser?

I wouldn't be doing this if in the first place I had a way to serialize to JSON with the ability to preserve key order.

Comment: There isn't much we can do to control the default/assumption of XMLSerializer and what firefox generated is not an invalid document but the implementation details of namespace handling. You can switch from 'xmlDoc.createElement("Name");' to 'xmlDoc.createElementNS("http://example.org/v1","Name");
' which should help you solve the issue

Comment: As others have said, try changing `var tag = xmlDoc.createElement(tagName);` to `var tag = xmlDoc.createElementNS('http://example.org/v1', tagName);` to have the elements in the namespace you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firefox serialization is correct.  When you create those elements with `createElement`, not `createElementNS`, that puts them in the null namespace (you can check by examining the `namespaceURI` of the elements after you create them).  However parsing the serialization Chrome produces would put them in the `http://example.org/v1` namespace.

And yes, the Firefox output is valid XML.  What made you think it's not valid?

I filed https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106531

Comment: IMO I don't think this is bug in Chrome rather it's issue with FF. General convention if go by XSD rules is all elements are by default namespace unqualified and one would use createElementNS only if there is need to override the parent element namespace. It would be very inconvenient to use createElementNS in every instance.

Comment: When you create an element there is no parent element.  So it's just created in the null namespace.  Note that there are proposals to use the XHTML namespace instead, in which case your elements would end up in the XHTML namespace, which is presumably just as bad for your purposes.  I agree it's inconvenient, but the namespace of an element is immutable, so has to be set at creation time.  In any case, both browsers put the elements in the null namespace when you create them.  Chrome just screws up serializing that.

Comment: My server is Apache CXF which rejects the document generated by Firefox as mentioned in the example using `createElement` only. 
Using `createElementNS` generates identical output on Chrome and Firefox which my server is able to handle correctly.

Comment: Well, the document as produced by Firefox probably doesn't match your schema, which is why it's being rejected.  But it's well-formed XML and _does_ match the DOM that was serialized.  The Chrome document is well-formed XML but does not match the DOM that was serialized, so ends up in the "two bugs cancel each other out" case.  ;)